# How can I enable/disable button components via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to divide the screen to 2 and use them as 2 different buttons (L,R) in Unity. But for the ones who are playing first time, I want to show the buttons' text and image to teach them what they do, and after that I want to disable buttons' image and text, they will be still interactable but invisible.

First time screen

[image: First time screen]

How can I ?

Comment: You explained what you want to do which involves many steps but you haven't explained where you're stuck. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way easier and more reliable than what you did would simply be do add something like this to your Button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class HintsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Image _image;
    private Text _text;

    private float _originalAlpha;

    // optional to control if Hints should be enabled on starting the App
    public bool enableAtStart;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // GetComponentInChildren finds the component on this object or any
        // child of this object recursively
        // (true) : make sure you also find the components if this or the child objects
        // are currently disabled

        // On this way you don't even have to rely on that the Image is on the 
        // Button GameObject or below in the hierachy
        _image = GetComponentInChildren<Image>(true);
        _text = GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);

        if(_image)
        {
            _originalAlpha = _image.color.a;
        }

        // optional to controll if Hints should be enabled on starting the App
        ShowHints(enableAtStart);
    }

    public void ShowHints(bool isVisible)
    {
        // Skip if no Image found
        if (_image)
        {
             var color = _image.color;
             color.a = isVisible ? _originalAlpha : 0;
             _image.color = color;
        }

        // Skip if no Text found
        if (_text)
        {
            _text.enabled = isVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

Then from any other script, you simply can do e.g.

```
// TODO somehow get the reference either to the button GameObject or the Button component
var button;

button.GetComponent<HintsController>().ShowHints(false);
```

To disable hints.

Comment: Great, but you can't interact with a button after you disable it's image component.

Comment: @No-LifeDev you are right ofcourse! I updated my answer to instead set the images alpha to `0`. The problem here is that it somehow needs a `RaycastTarget` -> If the Image component is disabled completely, there is no RaycastTarget enabled anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used `button.image.enabled = bool value`for image component and `button.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(bool value)` for the text.

Comment: You can have a `SerializedField` of GameObject's, `[SerializeField] GameObject[] toHide;` , that you want to hide then assign them in hierarchy. You can then just call the game objects `SetActive` to false just like what you did but with more control on which game objects you want to disable.Using `GetChild` may give you a hard time if you have to modify the screens or elements.

Comment: See [myAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52924134/7111561) for a more reliable approach

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest just making an empty for each button in the scene view, name them left and right. drag you button images(sprites) onte the scene and size them to fill the camera with proper positioning. apply  `boxCollider2D` to both of the parent game objects(the empties you created and named left and right.) then you will need some light scripting.

pseudo-wise i would say:

you will use:

```
void OnMouseDown(){
//button touched
}
```

to see if the button is pressed.

when your tutorial is over you will set the image and text invisible with the code you mentioned above or something similar. this script goes on each button.

Comment: I just created 2 images which are on top of both buttons and  I set buttons' alpha values to zero, I just used different images instead of buttons' own imagesç

Comment: `Image` components won't be visible if not placed as child of a canvas. You could do that without using `SpriteRenderer` instead but you still would have to calculate manually how to make your both objects fit the Screen size ....